# How to set non-natural alignment of a .NET struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, alignment, pinvoke

I'm doing interop with some native library, which has some non-natural alignment feature which I want to simulate in .NET struct for the layout. Check these two structs:

```
public struct Int3
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public short A;
    public Int3 Xyz;
    public short B;
}
```

So, within .NET, it uses its own layout rule to create the layout, which is, alignment would be min(sizeof(primitiveSize), StructLayout.Pack). So the layout of MyStruct would be:

```
[oo--] MyStruct.A (2 bytes data and 2 bytes padding)
[oooo oooo oooo] MyStruct.Xyz (3 int, no padding)
[oo--] MyStruct.B (2 bytes data and 2 bytes padding)
```

What I want to do is, I want to change the alignment of Int3 to 8 bytes, like something:

```
[StructLayout(Alignment = 8)]
public struct Int3 { .... }
```

Then the layout of MyStruct would became:

```
[oo-- ----] MyStruct.A (2 bytes for data, and 6 bytes padding, to align next Xyz to 8
[oooo oooo oooo ----] MyStruct.Xyz (4 bytes padding for alignment of 8)
[oo-- ----] (6 bytes padding, because the largest alignment in this struct is 8)
```

So, my question is:

1) Is there such an attribute in .NET to control the non-natural alignment like this?

2) If there is no such built-in attribute, I know there are other attributes such as StructLayout.Explict, OffsetAttribute, StructLayout.Size, StructLayout.Pack. With these attributes, I can simulate this layout manually, but it is not easy to use. So My second question would be, is there a way to hook into .NET struct layout creation which I can interfere the struct layout? What I mean is, I can create a custom attribute to specify the alignment, and then I calculate the layout, but I don't know how to interfere the .NET to use that layout.

Regards, Xiang.

Comment: No. You need to use the attributes. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is, .NET will think the alignment of Int3 is 4, because it only check each members which is of primitive types, which is int in this example. But in some native code, for better performance, they need to think that Int3 could be aligned at 8 boundary, or even 16 bytes boundary. So .NET seems has no way to see the alignment of a non-primitive type.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure that I understand the problem, though. Why can't you just use attributes to change the alignment? Unless I'm misreading the question, I think you're looking for the [Pack field of the StructLayout attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx). Something like: `[StrutLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]`

Comment: @CodyGray I tried to use Pack attribute a lot, actually, the Pack = 8 just means the largest alignment is 8, but in MyStruct, it treats the alignment of Int3 as min(sizeof(int), Pack) = 4, that is exactly the problem, that is I want it to be min(sizeof(8), Pack) = 8. Which means, treat the whole Int3's alignment, not the largest alignment of its primitive members. You can try my example in code, and use Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(MyStruct), "Xyz") to test. it would be 4, not my exptected 8.

Comment: @xiang the documentation says otherwise. Is it wrong?

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is, if we don't set Pack, it is set by the platform, and in Intel CPU, the Pack = 8, which means, it is a 64bit processor. That works fine in most of the time. But in some other platform, such as what I'm doing with the Nvidia GPU, which has 128-bit bandwidth, so the largest of Pack became 128. But we do not have 128 bit primitive types, to maxium the usage, I have to use struct to bind 2 or 3 or 4 primitive together, and set its alignment to be larger, such as 8 or 16. But the .NET only treat pack for primitives, with min(sizeof(primitiveMemberType), Pack).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Acturally the document is wrong. Pack will not always equal to the alignment. the alignment would be min(sizeof(primitiveMemberType), Pack)

Comment: @CodyGray check the comments on this page, the doc is not accurate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan check the comments on this page, the doc is not accurate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: OK. Too bad they cannot get such a fundamental thing right.

Comment: I think that merits its own question. Quote the documentation, explain that you've seen different behavior. Ask why. Ask for a workaround.

Comment: @CodeGray I think I observed the same behavior as the comments on that page says. Pack is not alignment, if you set Pack=8 on struct Int3, the size is still 12, which is not multiple of 8. So this means, Pack does not equal to alignment. And there is no built-in Align attribute in .NET. So I have to explicitly define the layout. The main problem is .NET cannot treat struct member (like the Int3 Xyz) as a primitive type, and it just find the largest primitive member inside Int3, and use that size to calculate the padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to 'hook into .NET' like you want that I am aware of than StructLayout.Explicit (which is just such a mechanism). Interop is quite a specialized need and, beyond the standard WinAPI cases, you should not expect it to be easy. In your case, unless you are dealing with truly large numbers of different structs with this unusual alignment, it's better to spell it out longhand with StructLayout.Explicit on MyStruct.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that there is no other way after googling it. Thanks for confirm this. In fact, I'm coding a CUDA language translator in F#, so CUDA C has such concept as __align__(x), and if use StructLayout.Explicit, that works, but need more work to check the layout, not simply like CUDA to just attaching an attribute to that struct.

Comment: look at Cudify if you want to have manged c# for cuda http://cudafy.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MeirionHughes Thanks, I know CUDAfy. Actually I'm creating a new library upon F# for CUDA: https://www.quantalea.net/products/introduction/  And in CUDAfy, I didn't see how they control the struct alignment, do you know how to do that in CUDAfy?

Answer (score 1):

Almost any structure will be stored as part of a heap object (either as a class field, or as a field of a struct that is stored as a class field, etc.)  The .net 32 platform aligns objects on the Large Object Heap to 16-byte boundaries, but other objects to 4-byte boundaries.  Unless an object is manually allocated on the LOH, or is an array of more than 999 doubles [due to a truly atrocious hack, IMHO], there is no meaningful way to assure anything more specific than 4-byte alignment.  Even if at some moment in time an unpinned struct is 16-byte aligned, any arbitrary GC cycle might relocate it and change that alignment.